# Issue with rails installation

Tags: 14.04, rails

I have installed rails on my Ubuntu 14.04 system following the instructions mentioned in this [DigitalOcean article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-on-ubuntu-14-04-using-rvm). Note that I am installing rails in my local system and not in DigitalOcean - I just followed the instructions to install rails from there.

I follow the instructions mentioned in the "Quick Way" section.

Everything went fine. No hiccups during installation. I also ran the `source` command as instructed at the end of that section.

I also managed to create a rails application (just started learning) and played around a bit. No complains.

Now, this happened a couple of days ago.

Today, I try to start the server using the command `$ rails server` and I get the following reply -

```
The program 'rails' can be found in the following packages:
 * ruby-railties-3.2
 * ruby-railties-4.0
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

I do not understand what happened. I suspected that some automatic update happened that overwrote the installed packages so I tried the DigitalOcean rails installation again.

Now, I am in a terminal in which I carried out the installation commands. rails has been installed and I am able to play with it.

However, I noticed that if I opened another terminal and tried using the rails command, I again get the same message as above indicating that rails is not installed.

What is happening here? How can I ensure that the rails installation stays across the terminals and more importantly that I do not lose it when I restart the system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The article you linked describes how to install as an *unprivileged user* - in other words, the files go into your user directory rather than into system directories. The standard shell environment doesn't know how to find these files, so the step

```
source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

given in the instructions is necessary in order to create a suitable environment *in your current shell*. If you leave the current shell (for example, switching to a different terminal, or logging out) you will need to run the `source` command again.

If you want to make the environment persistent, you should be able to add the command to your ~/.bashrc file as described here [RVM Command: source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4842566)

Comment: You are right. I have to keep running the source command. I will try the link to add the command to my ~/.bashrc file and let you know if it works

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`sudo apt-get install mysql-client libmysqlclient-dev`

above was needed for me, then:

`gem install bundler`

`bundle`